# Trouble with PHPMailer and iCloud SMTP Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, smtp, wordpress, icloud

I'm currently facing an issue with PHPMailer while trying to send emails using iCloud SMTP for my WordPress blog. I have followed the steps to configure PHPMailer with app-specific passwords provided by Apple, but I keep getting the "SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed" message in the logs.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Verified that the app-specific password is correctly generated for my iCloud email address.
2. Double-checked that I'm using the correct SMTP server, port, and encryption settings in my PHPMailer script.
3. Ensured that there are no typos or syntax errors in the PHPMailer configuration.
4. Checked the server firewall settings to allow outgoing connections on port 587.
5. Enabled PHPMailer's SMTP debugging, but the responses from the server haven't provided a clear indication of the issue.

Below is a snippet of the PHPMailer debug output:

```
DEBUG: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
DEBUG: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
DEBUG: CLIENT -> SERVER: [Base64 encoded version of app-specific password]
DEBUG: SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
DEBUG: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
DEBUG: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I have also manually tested the SMTP connection using Telnet, and I received a "Connection closed by foreign host" message after the `AUTH LOGIN` command.

I am confident that the credentials and settings are correct, so I'm puzzled about what could be causing the authentication failure. Has anyone else encountered this issue with PHPMailer and iCloud SMTP authentication? Are there any additional steps or configurations I should check to resolve this problem?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!